# Terraform : How lambda to refer s3 in terraform resource `aws_lambda_function`

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My lambda node source code is inside the s3 bucket as a zip file
I want that source to be uploaded while executing the `aws_lambda_function`

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "terraform_lambda_func" {
  s3_bucket     = var.bucket_name
  s3_key        = "${var.zip_file_name}.zip"
  function_name = var.lambdaFunctionName
  role          = aws_iam_role.okta-iam-v1.arn
  handler       = "index.handler"
  runtime       = "nodejs16.x"
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. If you want to upload a zip file via a lambda function, I'm not sure how that is terraform related, but I'm guessing you mean you want the lambda to reference the distribution otherwise pushed to S3. Maybe you can clarify a bit. And consider making a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and debugging details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanting it doesn't cut it because that's now the way the relantionship between a lambda and its code works.

What the `aws_lambda_function` resource does is is to say: "there is a lambda function and its code is there in that S3 bucket".

Because updating the file in the bucket doesn't automatically update the code that lambda, this resource doesn't have a way to reference new file content directly.

To do so, you need an `aws_s3_object` resource that is able to upload a new file to lambda.

To trigger the actual update of the lambda, you also need to pass the file hash to the `aws_lambda_function`. Since the `aws_s3_object` resource expors a source_hash property, you can link them as such.

See [How to update aws_lambda_function Terraform resource when ZIP package is changed on S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69410249/how-to-update-aws-lambda-function-terraform-resource-when-zip-package-is-changed)